# Laravel - Pass data to blade component directly from class

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a header component that has its own data, I do not need it to receive attributes from the parent so I have set the following class:

/app/View/components/pdf/DocumentHeader.php

```
class DocumentHeader extends Component
{

    public $prefs;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
        $this->prefs = Helper::getPreferencesAssoc();
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.pdf.DocumentHeader');
    }
}
```

Then my DocumentHeader component blade look as follow

```
<div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                @if(!empty($prefs['LOGO']))
                    <img width="200" src="{{ $prefs['LOGO'] }}" />
                @endif
            </td>
            
            <td width="50%" class="text-right">
                <h6>{{$prefs['COMPANY_NAME']}}</h6>
                {!! nl2br( strip_tags($prefs['INVOICE_ADDRESS']) ) !!}<br/>
                @if( !empty($prefs['INVOICE_TEL']) )
                    Tel: {{$prefs['INVOICE_TEL']}}<br/>
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

All very simple and it works locally but when I push this to production it keep saying that $prefs is not defined :(

I have tried adding:

```
return view('components.pdf.DocumentHeader')->with([
            'prefs' => Helper::getPreferencesAssoc()
        ]);
```

But it does not work in production either... any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: try this return view('components.pdf.DocumentHeader ',[
            'prefs' => Helper::getPreferencesAssoc()]
        );

Comment: then <x-DocumentHeader :prefs="$prefs"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your folder names to pascal case.
So, instead of

```
/app/View/components/pdf/DocumentHeader.php
```

it should be

```
/app/View/Components/Pdf/DocumentHeader.php
```

Reference can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31919#issuecomment-832828782).

They also suggested to run these commands:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
```